# Panda SQL in Python to analyse a large data set

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I have a panda data frame, which contains the following structure:

UserID     EmailOpenRank 

 User1      1

 User1      2

 User1      3

 User2      1

 User2      2

 User3      1

 User3      2

 User3      4

 User3      5

 …..    …....

---

The 'EmailOpenRank' field captures the sequential event (DF). If the number appear in a sequence that means (1,2, 3) that many times the email is opened by a user sequentially. I provided the example in the description. The question is out of 10 million users, what will be the appropriate SQL query (Pandasql) so that I can tell 9 million people opened 3 consecutive emails and 1 million people opened 4 consecutive emails.

Using pandasql, I want to figure out the total number of users, who opened 2 consecutive emails, 3 consecutive emails, 4 consecutive emails, etc., from the column 'EmailOpenRank' columns. For example, User1 opened 3 consecutive emails based on the rank, User2 has opened 2 consecutive emails, Users3 has opened 4 consecutive emails.

How can I make a start on this?

Comment: Is this ordered by occurrence? Because it seems you just need to GROUP BY User ID and count n as it stands

Comment: Usually email open stats are based on hits. What is "rank"?

Comment: @ Bruno: Yes,  it is an ordered occurrence. That's the way, the derived column 'EmailOpenRank' was constructed.

Comment: @halfer : that's a different topic. If you have the appropriate solution for this, then let me know.

Comment: I don't think the question is clear enough for someone to give an answer. I encourage you to edit the question and give as much information as possible, so that readers might consider reopening it.

Comment: @halfer. I don't have much to add. The 'EmailOpenRank' field captures the sequential event (DF). If the number appear in a sequence that means (1,2, 3) that many times the email is opened by a user sequentially. I provided the example in the description.  The question is out of 10 million users, what will be the appropriate SQL query (Pandasql) so that I can tell 9 million people opened 3 consecutive emails and 1 million people opened 4 consecutive email. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. This question shows no research effort. Please show us what have you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo really appreciate if there are more constructive inputs than the comments you shared. While there is merit to your statement, anyone who needs solutions/ suggestions/inputs comes to an online forum from others' experiences and expertise. This is a hard problem atleast for me. I have tried multiple days before decided to go to StackOverflow and to share it with others. I don't receive anything constructive maybe I need to move on.

Comment: @iqs I'm sorry but what I mean is that you didn't show any SQL query you tried and failed. Therefore readers have the feeling you didn't try anything. Question on Stack Overflow get more attention and better answers if they show some effort from the asker. If you don't know yet, there's a quality review queue for questions on SO where users with enough reputation can vote to close low quality question, comment etc. I only gave you an advice to improve your question. Believe or not, it will help you with getting the answer you need.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo. Thanks for the clarification. This is what I attempted in the past:                                                                                   
                                                                                           
pd.read_sql("SELECT count(distinct(User_Id)), Email_Open_Rank FROM Table where ((Email_Open_Rank=1) and (Email_Open_Rank= 2) and (Email_Open_Rank= 3)) group by User_Id", con)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Thanks.This is what I attempted for 3 consecutive emails open 
 AA= pd.read_sql("SELECT count(distinct(User_Id)), EmailOpenRank FROM Table where ((EmailOpenRank=1) and (EmailOpenRank= 2) and (EmailOpenRank= 3)) group by User_Id", con)                                                                     However, I don't think approach maybe not correct. For an individual user,  opened 2 consecutive emails, then EmailOpenRank column will capture the values sequentially.

Comment: You need a nested query I think. Perhaps I will have some time to get into it later today.

Comment: I agree with you. I was also made an attempt another way. Just sharing this so that it may help you think further. For each user, if an email was sent, we can create a send_rank (column) and if they opened the email then also there exist the EmailOpenRank column (displayed in the data). For example, if 100 emails were sent to user 1, only 50 were opened, in some cases, consecutively and in other cases not consecutively. The question is how many users opened 3 consecutive emails, how many users open 2 consecutive emails, etc. out of 10 million users within the data set.